# textmate & zen coding

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, emmet

I would to use Zen Coding (version 0.7) for TextMate (version 1.5.10).

It works for the simple shortcuts like `div#` which is translated to `<div id=""></div>`
However, when I try to use `div#divId` or `li*5`, it doesn't work. I try to autocomplete with tab or `ctrl + e`, but it seems to not function.

Do you have an idea of to fix this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Camille.

Answer (score 4):

If you do have all 3 installed, remember to press command + E instead of tab to trigger the zen coding. (just spent half a day on that :))

Answer (score 2):

Note: to fully install in TextMate, you’ll need to download three bundles. At the time of this writing, the three download links are titled as:

1. **Zen.Coding-TextMate.v0.3.zip (implements zen-coding)**
2. TextMate.Zen.HTML.1.3.zip (implements HTML functionality)
3. TextMate.Zen.CSS.1.3.zip (implements CSS functionality)

Reference: http://mondaybynoon.com/20090817/the-art-of-zen-coding-bringing-snippets-to-a-new-level/